# carousel distorting on change over

Tags: html, css, carousel

when my carousel slider 'changes over', there is a slight "distortion", what do i do to get rid of it please?

basically the desired effect is to keep it smooth while changing to next slide,right know it appears to jump

Thanks

codepen below

https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/BxwVdJ

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h4>We have a very unusal computer program which had some very unusal problems that were not in the program manual. Ravi rose to the challenge and has very good problem solving abilities. Ravi is also very good at explaining things in plain English and I recommend writing down what is explained. People are welcome to contact us for anymore information.</h4>
      <h2>Bruce & Bev A. - Sunnyhills,Auckland</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h4>PC Handyman is a business I use regualrily to assist me with my office needs, from building my business website to help in seting up all my IT equipment for my small office, he is patient, thorough and is a please to work with</h4>
      <h2>Craig M. Data Analytics NZ</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h4>As I am an elderly person, I often need help with setting up and a bit of training with my computer and phone, PC handyman are always punctual and have an ability to explain tech matters in a simple and non technical way!</h4>
      <h2>Wendy E. Howick</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding style from `.carousel-inner` and add the padding on `.carousel-item` and you are good to go.

Comment: Hi Himangshu,thanks it seemed to work when it slides from 2-3..but slide one seems bigger still codepen https://codepen.io/nightcoder21/pen/BxwVdJ

Comment: That's because the content of slide one is more than that of slide 2 and slide 3. Just add this style min-height: 197px; on .carousel-item and you are good to go.

Comment: perfect,thank you sir,your answer was absolutely correct!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding style from `.carousel-inner` and add the padding on `.carousel-item` and you are good to go.

or

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h4>We have a very unusal computer program which had some very unusal problems that were not in the program manual. Ravi rose to the challenge and has very good problem solving abilities. Ravi is also very good at explaining things in plain English
        and I recommend writing down what is explained. People are welcome to contact us for anymore information.</h4>
      <h2>Bruce & Bev A. - Sunnyhills,Auckland</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h4>PC Handyman is a business I use regualrily to assist me with my office needs, from building my business website to help in seting up all my IT equipment for my small office, he is patient, thorough and is a please to work with</h4>
      <h2>Craig M. Data Analytics NZ</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h4>As I am an elderly person, I often need help with setting up and a bit of training with my computer and phone, PC handyman are always punctual and have an ability to explain tech matters in a simple and non technical way!</h4>
      <h2>Wendy E. Howick</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<!-- Footer -->
<section id="footer">
  <div class="container mb-1">
    <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-md-left mb-2">



    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-5">
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline social text-center">
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-2 text-center text-white">
        <p>PC Handyman NZ - Small business / Home office IT solutions</p>
        <p class="h6">&copy All right Reversed.<a class="text-green ml-2" href="https://www.sunlimetech.com" target="_blank">PC Handyman 2018</a></p>
      </div>
      </hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



</body>




<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>



/* ABOUT US PAGE. */

.carousel-item {
  max-height: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.services-header {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.bullet-points {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bullet-points p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.gaza {
  background-color: #ff0808;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 1600 900'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='a' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%25' y2='0'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23F80' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23F80'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='b' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='100%25' gradientTransform='rotate(0,960,474)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23909' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23909'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23a)' width='1600' height='900'/%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23b)' width='1600' height='900'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/* carousel. */

.carousel-inner {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  /*    padding:1.5rem; */
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  background-color: #00b7ff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='540' height='450' viewBox='0 0 1080 900'%3E%3Cg fill-opacity='.1'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='90 150 0 300 180 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='90 150 180 0 0 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='270 150 360 0 180 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='450 150 360 300 540 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='450 150 540 0 360 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='630 150 540 300 720 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='630 150 720 0 540 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='810 150 720 300 900 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='810 150 900 0 720 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='990 150 900 300 1080 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='990 150 1080 0 900 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='90 450 0 600 180 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='90 450 180 300 0 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='270 450 180 600 360 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='270 450 360 300 180 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='450 450 360 600 540 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='450 450 540 300 360 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='630 450 540 600 720 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='630 450 720 300 540 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='810 450 720 600 900 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='810 450 900 300 720 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='990 450 900 600 1080 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='990 450 1080 300 900 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='90 750 0 900 180 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='270 750 180 900 360 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='270 750 360 600 180 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='450 750 540 600 360 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='630 750 540 900 720 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='630 750 720 600 540 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='810 750 720 900 900 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='810 750 900 600 720 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='990 750 900 900 1080 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='180 0 90 150 270 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='360 0 270 150 450 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='540 0 450 150 630 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='900 0 810 150 990 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='0 300 -90 450 90 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='0 300 90 150 -90 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='180 300 90 450 270 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='180 300 270 150 90 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='360 300 270 450 450 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='360 300 450 150 270 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='540 300 450 450 630 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='540 300 630 150 450 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='720 300 630 450 810 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='720 300 810 150 630 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='900 300 810 450 990 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='900 300 990 150 810 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='0 600 -90 750 90 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='0 600 90 450 -90 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='180 600 90 750 270 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='180 600 270 450 90 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='360 600 270 750 450 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='360 600 450 450 270 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='540 600 630 450 450 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='720 600 630 750 810 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='900 600 810 750 990 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='900 600 990 450 810 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='0 900 90 750 -90 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='180 900 270 750 90 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='360 900 450 750 270 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='540 900 630 750 450 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='720 900 810 750 630 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='900 900 990 750 810 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='1080 300 990 450 1170 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='1080 300 1170 150 990 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='1080 600 990 750 1170 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='1080 600 1170 450 990 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='1080 900 1170 750 990 750'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-inner img {
  opacity: .8;
}

section .section-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#footer {
  background: red !important;
  height: 15rem;
  color: blue;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#footer h5 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #eeeeee;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}

#footer ul.social li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}

#footer ul.social li a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}

#footer ul.social li:hover a i {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#footer ul.social li a,
#footer ul.quick-links li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#footer ul.social li a:hover {
  color: #eeeeee;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li {
  padding: 3px 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li:hover {
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li:hover a i {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.featurette-divider {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.col {
  color: black;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 35px 0;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

a {
  color: #26a5d3;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #26a5d3;
}

#contact {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/735911/pexels-photo-735911.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  color: #f4f4f4;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

textarea.form-control {
  height: 100px;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* ABOUT US PAGE. */

.carousel-item {
  max-height: 60vh;
  height: 60vh;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.services-header {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.bullet-points {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.bullet-points p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.gaza {
  background-color: #ff0808;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%25' height='100%25' viewBox='0 0 1600 900'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='a' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='0' y1='0' x2='100%25' y2='0'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23F80' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23F80'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3ClinearGradient id='b' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='100%25' gradientTransform='rotate(0,960,474)'%3E%3Cstop offset='0' stop-color='%23909' stop-opacity='0'/%3E%3Cstop offset='1' stop-color='%23909'/%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23a)' width='1600' height='900'/%3E%3Crect fill='url(%23b)' width='1600' height='900'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


/* carousel. */

.carousel-inner {
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  /*  padding:1.5rem; */
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  background-color: #00b7ff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='540' height='450' viewBox='0 0 1080 900'%3E%3Cg fill-opacity='.1'%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='90 150 0 300 180 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='90 150 180 0 0 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='270 150 360 0 180 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='450 150 360 300 540 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='450 150 540 0 360 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='630 150 540 300 720 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='630 150 720 0 540 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='810 150 720 300 900 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='810 150 900 0 720 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='990 150 900 300 1080 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='990 150 1080 0 900 0'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='90 450 0 600 180 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='90 450 180 300 0 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='270 450 180 600 360 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='270 450 360 300 180 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='450 450 360 600 540 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='450 450 540 300 360 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='630 450 540 600 720 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='630 450 720 300 540 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='810 450 720 600 900 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='810 450 900 300 720 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='990 450 900 600 1080 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='990 450 1080 300 900 300'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='90 750 0 900 180 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='270 750 180 900 360 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='270 750 360 600 180 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='450 750 540 600 360 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='630 750 540 900 720 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='630 750 720 600 540 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='810 750 720 900 900 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='810 750 900 600 720 600'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='990 750 900 900 1080 900'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='180 0 90 150 270 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='360 0 270 150 450 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='540 0 450 150 630 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='900 0 810 150 990 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='0 300 -90 450 90 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='0 300 90 150 -90 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='180 300 90 450 270 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='180 300 270 150 90 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='360 300 270 450 450 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='360 300 450 150 270 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='540 300 450 450 630 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='540 300 630 150 450 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='720 300 630 450 810 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='720 300 810 150 630 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='900 300 810 450 990 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='900 300 990 150 810 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='0 600 -90 750 90 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='0 600 90 450 -90 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='180 600 90 750 270 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='180 600 270 450 90 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='360 600 270 750 450 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23999' points='360 600 450 450 270 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='540 600 630 450 450 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='720 600 630 750 810 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='900 600 810 750 990 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='900 600 990 450 810 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='0 900 90 750 -90 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23444' points='180 900 270 750 90 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='360 900 450 750 270 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23AAA' points='540 900 630 750 450 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='720 900 810 750 630 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='900 900 990 750 810 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23222' points='1080 300 990 450 1170 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23FFF' points='1080 300 1170 150 990 150'/%3E%3Cpolygon points='1080 600 990 750 1170 750'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23666' points='1080 600 1170 450 990 450'/%3E%3Cpolygon fill='%23DDD' points='1080 900 1170 750 990 750'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.carousel-inner img {
  opacity: .8;
}

section .section-title {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#footer {
  background: red !important;
  height: 15rem;
  color: blue;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#footer h5 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 3px solid #eeeeee;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#footer a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}

#footer ul.social li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}

#footer ul.social li a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}

#footer ul.social li:hover a i {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

#footer ul.social li a,
#footer ul.quick-links li a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#footer ul.social li a:hover {
  color: #eeeeee;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li {
  padding: 3px 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s all ease;
  -moz-transition: .5s all ease;
  transition: .5s all ease;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li:hover {
  padding: 3px 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li a i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#footer ul.quick-links li:hover a i {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.featurette-divider {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.col {
  color: black;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0 0 35px 0;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

a {
  color: #26a5d3;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #26a5d3;
}

#contact {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/735911/pexels-photo-735911.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260');
  color: #f4f4f4;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

textarea.form-control {
  height: 100px;
}


}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h4>We have a very unusal computer program which had some very unusal problems that were not in the program manual. Ravi rose to the challenge and has very good problem solving abilities. Ravi is also very good at explaining things in plain English
        and I recommend writing down what is explained. People are welcome to contact us for anymore information.</h4>
      <h2>Bruce & Bev A. - Sunnyhills,Auckland</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h4>PC Handyman is a business I use regualrily to assist me with my office needs, from building my business website to help in seting up all my IT equipment for my small office, he is patient, thorough and is a please to work with</h4>
      <h2>Craig M. Data Analytics NZ</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h4>As I am an elderly person, I often need help with setting up and a bit of training with my computer and phone, PC handyman are always punctual and have an ability to explain tech matters in a simple and non technical way!</h4>
      <h2>Wendy E. Howick</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<!-- Footer -->
<section id="footer">
  <div class="container mb-1">
    <div class="row text-center text-xs-center text-sm-left text-md-left mb-2">



    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-5">
        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline social text-center">
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();"><i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
          <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="javascript:void();" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 mt-2 mt-sm-2 text-center text-white">
        <p>PC Handyman NZ - Small business / Home office IT solutions</p>
        <p class="h6">&copy All right Reversed.<a class="text-green ml-2" href="https://www.sunlimetech.com" target="_blank">PC Handyman 2018</a></p>
      </div>
      </hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



</body>




<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```